# Modify vscode snippet by regex: TitleCase and SNAKE_CASE

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I have two questions for vscode snippets+regex;

1. I have a pathname like `some-component` and I need to generate an output like `SomeComponent` using vscode snippet.
2. I need to input `sendData` and return an string like `const sendData = createMessage(SEND_DATA);`

How can I do this using regex on vscode snippet?

Answer (score 0):

1. `"${TM_DIRECTORY/(.*)/${1:/pascalcase}/g}" you didn't really provide enough info on how you are getting your pathName, so this is just one possibility, perhaps` RELATIVE_FILEPATH` works for you.
2. `"$1 = createMessage(${1/(([^A-Z]+)(\\w*))/${2:/upcase}_${3:/upcase}/});"`

split the input `sendData` into 2 capture groups $2 and $3.  Upcase them both in the transform.

```
"sendData": {
  "prefix": "cm",
  "body": [
    "${TM_DIRECTORY/(.*)/${1:/pascalcase}/}",

    // simpler form if ONLY two "words" like "sendData"
    "$1 = createMessage(${1/(([^A-Z]+)(\\w*))/${2:/upcase}_${3:/upcase}/});",

   // for any number of words, like "sendDataTwoThreeFour" use this:
   "$1 = createMessage(${1/([a-z]*)([A-Z][a-z]*)/${1:/upcase}${2:+_}${2:/upcase}/g});"
  ]
}
```

`${1/([a-z]*)([A-Z][a-z]*)/${1:/upcase}${2:+_}${2:/upcase}/g}` get the first word "send" into capture group 1 and the other words like "Data" or "Two", etc. into **subsequent matches'** capture group 2.  [So the `g` flag at the end is very important.]

Upcase group1.  Then if there is a group 2 `${2:+_}`  add `_`. Then upcase group2.

The only case this will not work on is `send` with nothing else.  It still prints out the all the text just doesn't upcase `send` if it is by itself.  There is probably a way to include that...

Edit: And here it is:

`"$1 = createMessage(${1/([a-z]*)([A-Z][a-z]*)|([a-z]+)/${1:/upcase}${3:/upcase}${2:+_}${2:/upcase}/g});"`

now a bare `send` will be put into group 3 and upcased.  For the rest of the matches there will not be a group 3 so `${3:/upcase}` returns nothing.